# Good-guy-bad-guy-routines

Tags: golden-calf-egel

Concerning the sin of the golden calf, the Torah says:

Moses went back to God and said, “Alas, this people is guilty of a great sin in making for themselves a god of gold." [Ex. 32:31]

The Yalkut Shimoni comments:

God then said to Moses: You, too, are angry with them? We cannot both be angry. When you see Me pour hot water, you pour cold, and when you see Me pour cold, you pour hot.” [Yalkut Shimoni on Torah 392:2]

I know I posted this in PTIJ and it was deep-sixed. So let me ask a serious question.  The Source says *plainly* that God favors good-guy-bad-guy-routines as an effective way to maintain balance.
Are there any other interpretations of the passage ?

Comment: "Do you reject this teaching because it doesn't sit well with you?" This sounds like a solicitation for opinion, which is frowned upon around here (see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) ) Perhaps consider modifying your question so that it gets a better chance at being addressed by the community.

Comment: The second question is the operative one for those who would prefer not to answer the first.

Comment: Is there any reason to think that this is a departure from the classical balancing of *din* and *rahamim* which we see as a theme come up frequently in rabbinic literature? If I recall correctly there is another midrash that even utilizes the same language of a hot (din) and cold (rahamim) water at the creation of the world, with God choosing to mix the two lest the vessels of creation crack or congeal.

Comment: No, there isn't.  It is not a different interpretation.

Comment: So perhaps you can elaborate in what exactly you are trying to figure out.